# Nvarchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Why do we need to add `N'பட்டப்பகலில்'` for unicode strings in nvarchar.

We are inserting unicode as well as non unicode string in a column that is nvarchar type, Since type of a column is nvarchar why do we need to add `N''` before unicode string, we will not be knowing what is unicode and non unicode string .

Do we have any way we can insert unicode and non unicode in nvarchar field without mentioning N in it.

Comment: In short: no. Nor do I see what the problem is: simply prefix *all* strings with `N` and you'll be fine; in case of a `VARCHAR`, the value will just be converted. It's not like you're getting some sort of wonderful performance boost by writing your literals as non-Unicode. In client applications, this is a non-issue anyway because you should be using parameters of the appropriate type, not literals (and so you have no prefixes to worry about).

Comment: What makes you think you have to use `N''`?  Are you getting some error when you don't?

Comment: No. If you omit the N it is varchar data. The N is the syntax required to indicate that it is unicode data.

Answer (score 3):

> Since type of a column is `nvarchar` why do we need to add `N''`

By the time the *value* is *assigned* to a column or variable, it's already been processed as a string literal.<sup>1</sup>

It's therefore far too late to consider the *type* of the column or variable to decide how to process it. Indeed, it may not be assigned to a column or variable at all - it may be part of a larger expression.

That's why you have to separately indicate the type of each literal. But as others have commented, there's no great penalty in just marking all of your literals as unicode (unless you're working with lots of ~6000 character literals).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is the same as many other languages where the type of an *expression* has to be determined without any regard to *if* it's going to be assigned to a particular variable, and therefore the type of such a variable does not play a part in determining the type of the expression.

Comment: Honestly, it's time to have "N" literals become the default, and have a new literal syntax prefix you can use to force narrow/ascii literals in the rare case where it causes a performance problem or you need to force a unicode=>ascii conversion.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - what we should do is *stop writing SQL*, or at least any that contains embedded data. We don't have to use `N` when we're using a binding from any decent language that has native unicode and supports parameters. (Admittedly, sometimes we have SQL that contains constant data and it feels a bit *wasteful* to parameterize)

Answer (score 2):

Putting `N` at the start of a literal string means it is an `nvarchar`. The difference between `'abc'` and `N'abc'` is that the first literal string is a `varchar(3)`, and the second is a `nvarchar(3)`.

Why is it important? Well one reason is  that an `nvarchar` is double the size of a `varchar`, so creating a good query plan for the size of the values you have is incredibly important. Also, an `nvarchar` can only have a maximum length of 4000 before you need to use `MAX`. A `varchar` can have up to 8000.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is type nvarchar, then everything is stored as unicode. Even if you use characters that would not need unicode to store, they are still stored as unicode. So you can't insert "non-unicode" strings.

You can omit the `N` if you'd like, if you're not using any special characters. But SQL Server will just convert it to unicode before storing it.

Comment: If a give a unicode string without N that is showing as ? though it's a nvarchar field. So my question is evn though its a unicode(nvarchar) field, why do we need to pass N only for unicode data?

Comment: Are you putting Roman characters (characters that normally would be in the ASCII table) or other characters?